# Void pointers in C used in stacks

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am writing a program that implements a stack in c.  I want each node to take any type of data(ie int char struct etc) if I declare my node struct as

```
    typedef struct node{
           void *data;
           struct node *next;
   }Node;
```

Does that allow my void pointer data to point to any type of memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but there are some caveats involving dereferencing your void pointer to access the data inside.

Basically, say you have a node:

```
Node *node;
```

And you have some Point structure:

```
typedef struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
} Point;
```

And you put a point in a node:

```
Point *p = malloc(sizeof(Point));
p->x = 0;
p->y = 3;
node->data = p;
```

In order to access the members of the point, you have to use a typecast:

```
printf("%d\n", ((Point *)node->data)->x);
```

Or you can assign a pointer of the correct type and copy the void pointer:

```
Point *p = node->data;
printf("%d\n", p->x);
```

Because this won't work:

```
printf("%d\n", node->data->x);
```

That's because a void pointer contains no type information for the compiler to make sense of what's being pointed to by a void pointer.

And that's pretty much all you need to know about how to use void pointers.

Answer (score 1):

> Does that allow my void pointer data to point to any type of memory?

Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Succinctly, yes.  It means you'll store a pointer to the `int`, etc, so that takes up space.  You also need to ensure that you know how to handle different types if you do not have homogeneous types in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible what you wanna to achieve but you need to take care of dereferencing the the void pointer.,what i am alluding is you have to type caste void pointer to appropriate type while dereferencing.